# How do I turn on Research Assistant in XCODE Version 3.2.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode3.2

Seems like a mystery to me.  I've read the referenced Q&A on this, but it still doesn't work.  A bug?  A Preference setting?
.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Select symbol then option-doubleClick. The little window pops up.

Answer (score 1):

The research assistant in 3.2 has been replaced with Quick help under the Help menu. Look there.

Answer (score 0):

*Research Assistant* was replaced by *Quick Help* in Xcode 3.2.  Quoting [What's New in Xcode 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/10-Articles/xcode_3_2.html):

> Xcode provides you with fast access to
>   documentation through an improved and
>   streamlined Documentation window and
>   Quick Help (a revamped implementation
>   of the Research Assistant).

And:

> Quick Help is a
>   lightweight window that provides
>   essential information about the symbol
>   selected in the text editor without
>   taking away the focus from the editor.
>   From Quick Help you can jump to the
>   header file that declares the symbol
>   or to the symbol’s API reference. For
>   details, see “Using the Research
>   Assistant” in Xcode Workspace Guide.

You can learn how to access it via "[Using Quick Help](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/200-Documentation_Access/documentation_access.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006920-CH260-SW1)" in any of the following ways:

- Help > Quick Help
- Ctrl-Command-?
- Option-Double-Click